# Leaflet.MovingMarker, set "destionation" event to rotate icon

Tags: leaflet

[MovingMarker](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker) can easily create icon moving ptah animation, it can pause halfway and continue moving.

But It did not provide events for listener status, when the icon moves to a certain node, I can change the direction(Like the rotate of the spinning airplane icon) of the icon.

[image]

For example:

```
let node1 = [48.8567, 2.3508];
let node2 = [50.45, 30.523333]
let node3 = [53.45, 31.523333]
var myMovingMarker = L.Marker.movingMarker([node1, node2,node3 ],
    [1000],[1000],[1000]).addTo(map);
myMovingMarker.start();

//MovingMarker did not provide this feature
myMovingMarker.on('location',(e)=>{
    // When the icon reaches a certain node(node1, node2 or node3), change the direction of the icon
})
```

Someone made similar suggestions in the [github issues](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker/issues/35), but no one answered.
He mentioned that this problem can be solved indirectly through the `"_loadLine"` function, but I don’t know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this Pull Request: https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker/pull/14

He added the event `lineIndexChanged`:

```
if (this._currentIndex !== index) {
            this.fire('lineIndexChanged', { lineIndex: index });
        }
```

Comment: `this.fire` is a listener function? What is the `this`, how can I use it?

Comment: look into the pull request. This code lines are added in the `_loadLine` function and can be used with `myMovingMarker.on('lineIndexChanged', (e)=> ... `